# Replace spaces by pluses in URLs in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, url

If I generate a URL in Symfony2 with spaces, for example:

```
example.com/some text
```

then this URL displayed on site like:

```
example.com/some%20text
```

How can I set up replacing spaces by pluses, not by %20?

In this case:

```
example.com/some+text
```

I need common solution, not adding |replace('%20','+') in all URLs.

Comment: Is You url are built with some 'slug' from db content ? If yes then you should use slugify. A bundle which implements this : https://github.com/cocur/slugify

Comment: (You don't need to use HTML to format your code samples here on Stack Overflow. Just make sure your code has a line break before and after, as per my edit).

Comment: Make a custom field type for url?

Comment: You could create a custom twig function (for example `path_plus`) that converted the string from space to + and then generated the URL from that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answers, I found my own solution.

In MainBundle\Resources\config\services.yml added

```
parameters:
    router.options.generator_base_class: Melofania\MainBundle\UrlGenerator
```

And created file MainBundle\UrlGenerator.php

```
namespace Melofania\MainBundle;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator as BaseUrlGenerator;

class UrlGenerator extends BaseUrlGenerator
{
    protected function doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens)
    {
        $url = parent::doGenerate($variables, $defaults, $requirements, $tokens, $parameters, $name, $referenceType, $hostTokens);

        return str_replace('%20', '+', $url);
    }
}
```

But the reverse procedure hasn't a solution yet. I mean, URL with pluses => route parameters with spaces in controller. I tried using UrlMatcher, but without success. If you have answer, please write it on this page:
[Convert values of route parameters dynamically in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754401/convert-values-of-route-parameters-dynamically-in-symfony-2)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it works for me. First I created a service to encode/decode url. So you `str_replace('--the escape character--','+')` in your controller (using a service or another alternative) you will have something like this:

```
myRoute:
    path: /{argument}
    controller: sampleController
```

Original url:

```
http://example.com/lorem+ipsum
```

So here your `sampleController` will get the `$argument` like this:

```
$argument = 'lorem+ipsum';
```

Here you just decode it:

```
$theOriginal = str_replace('+','%20',$argument);
```

For twig you just add the filter "Replace" like this if you need to display it:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')['argument']|replace('+',' --the escape character--')}}
```